# Drinking wine has a lot of positive sides that depend / depends on

Tags: singular-vs-plural, subject-verb-agreement

I am writing some sentences to tell my friends that they should drink some red wine in dinners.

> Drinking wine has a lot of positive sides that **[depend / depends]** on
>   which type of wine people purchase, for example, some doctors have
>   recommended people drink red wine because they are better for health.

I have stopped writing after this sentence, because I am not sure
whether I should use a singualr verb or not.
Here is the reason why I hesitate:
Drinking wine is singular, but a lot of positive sides is plural, 
so I am confused.

Comment: You have to ask yourself what depends on what. Is it positive sides that **depend** on the type of wine people purchase, or is it drinking wine that **depends** on the type of wine people purchase? Furthermore, it's grammatically amiss to refer to *red wine* as *they*.

Comment: Instead of **positive sides** you can use the word **benefits**. And do I still get the benefits if someone else buys the wine?  :)

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo  isn't that a **double** benefit?  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As userr2684291's comment points out, it depends on which noun is the *subject* of the verb "depend".  Is it "drinking wine" or is it "many side [effects]"?  You can go either way:

> **Drinking wine** has a lot of positive effects, and **depends** ...
>
> Drinking wine has a lot of **positive effects** that **depend** ...

However, the rest of your sentence makes it clear that it's the *effects* that vary depending on which wine is drunk.  So go with "depend".

Also, it's difficult to think of a sentence in which the gerund "drinking wine" can *depend* on anything, but let me give it a try:

> **Drinking wine** with friends **depends** entirely on whether there is wine to drink.  If they bring the wine, they are my friends.  If they show up empty handed, I show them the door!

Comment: @kitty also note my edited answer.  Using "that depend" links *effects* to *depend*.  If you want "drinking wine" to be the subject, you have to use a different conjunction.